# If $ad−bc \neq 0$, then the following matrix must have rank $2$. (True/False)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

The matrix $A$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$

Just started an intro to linear algebra
a class, and I understand what rank means, but I'm not sure how to work with letters.

I do know how to manipulate the matrix into reduced row-echelon form, and can get:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

I do realize this is of rank $2$. Is simply doing $\operatorname{rref}(A)$ enough to solve this? I'm just a little unsure because I know I can say that $A$ *can* have rank $2$, but *must* it?

Comment: Suppose it didn't have rank $2$. What would that imply?

Comment: There are a few scenarios that come to mind. Let's say it was above rank 2. Then it wouldn't be a 2x2 matrix anymore. Now let's say it was rank 1 or even 0. It could still be 2x2 but the determinant would be zero, implying that ad = bc (I took multivariable calculus before linear algebra so I'm familiar with the determinant of matrices). But according to the question that is not true. Does this help? And if so, how? I feel like that is proving the converse of the question.

Comment: So, rank $<2$ implies $\det{A}=0$, i.e. $ad-bc=0$. The question tells you that this is not the case. Hence the original assumption that rank $<2$ was incorrect, and so we must have rank $=2$.

Comment: Just to clarify: I know the rank can be lower with the same size matrix, but if the rank is higher then the matrix would have to be larger. Is it impossible for the matrix to change size? Like from 2x2 to 3x3?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $a$ is non-zero, then the first step of row reduction yields
$$
\pmatrix{
a&b\\c&d
} \to 
\pmatrix{a &b\\0& d - \frac {bc}a}
$$
We will end up with two pivots iff $d - \frac {bc}a \neq 0$.

If $a$ is zero, then show that we end up with two pivots if (and only if) both $b$ and $c$ are non-zero.

Comment: What does "pivot" mean?

Comment: @Hello in the row-echelon (or reduced row-echelon, i.e. row-reduced) form of a matrix, the leading non-zero entries of each (non-zero) row are sometimes referred to as "pivots".  Along these lines, the rank of a matrix is also the number of pivots in the corresponding row-echelon form matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If ad-bc$\neq$0 then AX=0 has a unique solution which is (0,0) since the trivial solution is always a solutions. Then dimnullspace=0 and so dimrange=2 and then the basis of range space contains 2 elements which is equivalent to saying that the row reduced echelon matrix equivalent to A has 2 non zero rows so the rank of the matrix is 2.

Comment: This doesn't add to the existing answer.